# Trouble with simple calculator program in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, calculator

I need to define a calculator for simple arithmetic expressions in Scheme. For example, when typing `(calculator '( 1 + 2))`, scheme interpreter will print `3`. The calculator will accept expression of any length, and the expression associates to the right. Eg, in `(calculator  '(1 + 1 - 2 + 3 ))` the expression is interpreted as `(1 + (1 - (2 + 3)))`, hence the value is `-3`. I'm assuming the expression has `+` and `-` operators only and there are no brackets in the input. I wrote this program so far:

```
#lang lazy
(define (calculator exp)
 (cond
   ((null? exp) 0)
   (= (length (exp)) 1 exp)
   (eq? '+ (cdr (cdr exp)) (+ (car exp) (calculator (cdr (cdr exp)))))
   (else (eq? '- (cdr (cdr exp)) (- (car exp) (calculator (cdr (cdr exp)))))))
```

But when I try something like `(calculator '(1 + 1 + 1))`, I get this error:

```
#%module-begin: allowed only around a module body in: (#%module-begin (define
(calculator exp) (cond ((null? exp) 0) (= (length (exp)) 1 exp) (eq? (quote +)
(cdr (cdr exp)) (+ (car exp) (calculator (cdr (cdr exp))))) (else (eq? (quote -)
(cdr (cdr exp)) (- (car exp) (calculator (cdr (cdr exp)))))))) (calculator
(quote (1 + 1 + 1))))
```

I'm very new to Scheme so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your error sounds more related to your programming environment than the actual Scheme code.  Your scheme code also has some issues though.  Syntax for `cond` is `(cond (test1 exp...) (test2 exp...) ...)`, so you need, for instance, `(cond ... ((= (length exp) 1) exp) ...)`, not what you have.  (I also changed `(exp)` to `exp` there, since (presumably), `exp`'s not a function, and you're not trying to call it.)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax in your code isn't correct.  As noted in the comment to your question, you've misplaced some parens.  In Scheme you get a large benefit in 'tracking parens' by indenting consistently.  Here is a version that gets you mostly there.

```
(define (calculator exp)
  (cond ((null? exp) 0)                 ; zero terms
        ((null? (cdr exp)) (car exp))   ; one  term only (assumed number)
        (else                           ; assumed three or more terms
          (let ((operand1 (car  exp))
                (operator (cadr exp))
                (operands (cddr exp)))
            ((case operator             ; convert operator, a symbol, to its function
               ((+) +)
               ((-) -))
             operand1
             (calculator operands)))))) ; calculate the rest
> (calculator '(1 + 2))
3
> (calculator '(1 - 2 + 3))
-4
```

Comment: (calculator '(1 - 2 + 3))
-4
WUT?

Comment: Per OP: (1 - 2 + 3) ==> (1 - (2 + 3) ==> (1 - 5) ==> -4

Comment: I understand why this code works that way, but it's not the order that should be...

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert

> 1 - 2 +  3

to

> (- 1 (+ 2 3))

you need to

1. cache value 1
2. apply - to the cached value 1 and the rest of the expression
3. cache value  2
4. apply + to the cached value 2 and the rest of the expression
5. cache value 3
6. return cached value 3 since your list is empty now

So your have 3 cases:

1) end of list => return cached value

otherwise toggle between

2) cache a value

3) apply the function to the cached value and the rest of the expression

Sample code:

```
(define (calculator exp)
  (define funcs (hasheq '+ + '- -))
  (let loop ((exp exp) (toggle #t) (val #f))
    (if (empty? exp)
        val ; 1) end of list => return cached value
        (if toggle
            (loop (cdr exp) #f (car exp)) ; 2) cache value
            ((hash-ref funcs (car exp)) val (loop (cdr exp) #t #f)))))) ; 3) apply the function to the cached value and the rest of the expression
```